# How to escape [ ] in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Let's say I have a folder with name "Folder [MyGitHub]" and it has one subfolder with name "1"

When I try the following powershell,

```
$sourcePath = "D:\Folder [MyGitHub]"
[array]$buildDirectories = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath | Sort-Object Name
Write-Output $BuildDirectories[0]
```

The exception is:

```
Cannot index into a null array. At line:1 char:1    + Write-Output $BuildDirectories[0]    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

I have tried escaping with backtick (`), backslash, single and double quotes, but the issue was not resolved. The code is working if [] are not present in the folder name string - example **Folder (MyGitHub)**.

Comment: `$buildDirectories = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourcePath | Sort-Object Name)`. To escape, use backticks: ```"D:\Folder ``[MyGitHub``]"``` or ```'D:\Folder `[MyGitHub`]'``` (notice that `"`-quoted strings need _double_ backticks)

Comment: `Get-ChildItem 'D:\Folder ``[MyGitHub``]'` or `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\Folder [MyGitHub]'`